# Choose between template function and auto type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++14, c++17

I have a generic question about template functions versus auto type deduction for functions.

For years, we have have been able to write template function :

```
template <class T> T add(T a,T b){
    return a+b;
}
```

There is a TS for using auto for function's parameters deduction

```
auto add(auto a,auto b){
    return a+b;
}
```

I though with auto, one had no way to get to the actual type and for instance use static members, but this works just fine :

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    static void bar(){std::cout<<"bar"<<std::endl;}
    static int i ;
};
int foo::i{0};
void t(auto f){
    decltype(f)::bar();
    std::cout<<    decltype(f)::i<<std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    t(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

So is there any reason to choose one instead of the other ?

Comment: C++14 does not allow you to use `auto` for function parameter types, only the return type can be deduced. What you're using (as an extension provided by your compiler) is syntax that'll eventually make its way into the standard whenever Concepts Lite gets standardized.

Comment: `auto` uses template type deduction for type anyway.

Comment: @FoggyDay: Two reasons mainly. The first is to avoid verbosity. The second is to avoid reduced maintainability due to redundant specifications of the same type.

Comment: @Praetorian : fixed from C++14 to a TS.  

After thinking, the only reason I see for using template function is to enforce several parameters to have the same type. While with auto, each type deduction is independent from each other.

Comment: @milleniumbug : wrong thread ?

Comment: Note that you can just write `f.bar()` and `f.i` to access the static members.

Comment: Writing `decltype(f)` 10 times can be rather annoying, compared to writing just `T`.

Comment: @T.C. `using T = decltype(f);` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious reason for this particular code would be that they don't really have the same semantics at all.

In particular, if you pass arguments of different types, the version using `auto` will deduce a type independently for each, then based on those deduce a type for the result.

Conversely, with the template version, you've specified exactly one type, so the arguments must both be the same type (and the result will be the same).

So, to get the code to be more nearly equivalent, you'd really need to write the template more like:

```
template <class T, class U> 
auto add(T a, U b) -> decltype(a+b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

This is obviously possible as well, but adds even more strength to the arguments in favor of using `auto` instead.

Comment: There are several ways in which your code is not equivalent to the auto version (decay, sfinae).

Comment: The "more like" was intended to cover the point that there *are* still some differences, but it probably doesn't hurt to be more explicit about the fact that it's still not really identical. I've edited to reflect that fact.

Comment: Why don't you use `template <class T, class U> 
auto add(T a, U b) {return a+b;}`
? It's C++14.

Comment: @Columbo: Because the whole point was to show how you'd do it *without* using `auto`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ahh, I thought the question was merely about the deduced parameter types, sorry.

Comment: @MarcGlisse What do you mean by decay?

Comment: @Columbo: I guess there's no particular reason you couldn't do that.

Comment: @Columbo if `a+b` returns a reference, the `->decltype` version of `add` returns a reference, while the `auto` version returns a value type (and decayed).  This can probably be fixed with a `decltype(auto) add(auto a, auto b){return a+b;}` version (but I'm not fully up to speed on the C++1z proposal for automatic template functions).

Comment: @Yakk Yes, `decltype(auto)` fixes it, since that is basically defined as deducing the type that `decltype` would yield. I totally forgot that `decltype` will consider the value category, I'll blame it on my sleep deprivation.

Answer (score 3):

In your code there are two different uses of `auto`, one in the parameters and another in the return type.  In the case of the parameters, each use of `auto` introduces a unique template type argument, so as Jerry mentions it would be equivalent to:

```
// 1
template <typename A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

In this case, if you have any constraint on the different type arguments (must be the same could be one, but there would be other) then the explicit template syntax provides a better alternative.  This is specially so if you want to use SFINAE on the arguments (by means of an additional template argument):

```
// 2
template <typename A, typename B, 
          typename _1 = typename A::iterator,  // A has nested iterator type
          typename _2 = typename B::iterator>  // So does B
auto f(A a, B b);
```

Note that I have intentionally avoided the use of SFINAE on the return type as it somehow interferes with your other use of `auto`, but this could be another option:

```
// 3
auto f(auto a, auto b) 
  ->     typename enable_if<has_nested_iterator<decltype(a)>::value
                         && has_nested_iterator<decltype(b)>::value, 
                           [return type] >::type;
```

But as you can see it becomes a bit more involved as you need to use a trailing return type and obtain the type trough the value by means of `decltype`.

The second use of `auto` in your example, which is quite different than this one, is in the return type to have a *deduced return type*.  The deduced return type is a feature that was already available in C++11 for lambdas, but has been generalized to all function templates.  The feature lets the compiler find the type returned by the function by inspecting the different `return` statements inside the body.  The advantage is that if your template has a single return expression, you can avoid having to type that expression twice, one for the return type another for the actual code:

```
// 4
auto add(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b) {  // 'a + b' here
   return a + b;                               // 'a + b' also here
}
```

The disadvantage is that the compiler needs to inspect the body of the function to determine the type that will be returned, and this is by necessity post type substitution. As such, the return statement from a function having a deduced type cannot be used in an SFINAE expression, potentially complicating the life of users of your function:

```
// 5
auto doAdd(auto a, auto b) 
  -> typename enable_if<is_integral<decltype(add(a,b))>>::type
{
   return add(a,b);
}
```

SFINAE will *not* remove the above `doAdd` overload from the overload resolution set causing a hard error if you call it as `doAdd(1, 1.)`.

Comment: *"In this case, if you have any constraint on the different type arguments [...] then the explicit template syntax provides a better alternative."* A better alternative to what? Given that `auto` parameters should be introduced via the Concepts TS, isn't the alternative to use the abbreviated template notation with concepts?

Comment: @dyp: In the answer I was referring to the good old `template<...>...` syntax, but since you bring the Concepts TS to the discussion, the TS brings multiple different syntaxes to the mix with different levels of flexibility and equivalencies.  The abbreviated template you mention cannot be used for the examples 2 and 3 in the answer, as `auto f(HasIterator a, HasIterator b)` forces the types of `a` and `b` to be the same, while the code in the answer requires that each type independently satisfies the concept.  I raised this, and suggested a modified version of the template-introduction [...]

Comment: ... syntax, that would allow `auto f(HasIterator{T} a, HasIterator{U} b)`, that is, have the user provide a name for the introduced template argument, same name represents same type, different name represents a new type.  Andrew came back to me saying that they had considered this in the past and rejected, but did not quite explain for what reasons. In conversations with other committee members I was told that Bjarne wants concepts to look just like types as conceptually it is just a placeholder for one. [...]

Comment: ... in the simpler cases this is really great, but it means that the abbreviated template notation does not allow the user to control which arguments are of the same or different types and forces the use of a heavier syntax for that case (for example, a `zip` algorithm that generates a sequence of `pair<T,U>` out of two sequences of `T` and `U`).  Personally I'd remove some of the alternatives for the syntax before getting it into the standard, and I pushed my company to provide that as part of the comments to the TS.

Comment: Other things that I dislike: `void f(auto a, auto b)` arguments of possibly different type, `void f(concept a, concept b)` arguments of the same type -- inconsistent; different locations of the requirements lead to different incompatible declarations; non-templates can be constrained and then more constrained: `void f(int);` < `void f(int) requires true;`. I don't see why having constrained functions in non-templated code [there's one: a friend that is defined inlined inside a template that exists or not depending on a trait of the template argument type, but that could be singled out].

Comment: *"The abbreviated template you mention cannot be used for the examples 2 and 3 in the answer, as `auto f(HasIterator a, HasIterator b)` forces the types of `a` and `b` to be the same"* Ah, I was worried that was the case. I couldn't remember if they've enforced it or not. I remembered the shorthand notation `MyConcept{T0, T1} void foo(T0, T1);` from an earlier Concepts Lite draft (has that feature been removed?) and thought that you could enforce the same types simply by some `is_same` like concept, so the default should be different types for each function parameter.

Comment: @dyp: That syntax is still there (I don't think they removed anything really), and is called *template-introduction*. Still in the example, the types *differ*, adding a constrain that they are the same is not useful, you can just leave it as `void f(HasIterator a, HasIterator b)`, which is equivalent to `HasIterator{T} void f(T a, T b)` and different than either 2 or 3 in the answer... so there you have it, multiple limited syntaxes, yet missing one that is both concise and flexible. At any rate, I don't think that a `is_same` concept would make a lot of sense... it is more of a test

Comment: Yes, I meant that the default should be different types for `a` and `b` in `void f(HasIterator a, HasIterator b)` and if you need to enforce having the same types, something like `HaveIteratorAndSame{A, B} void f(A, B)` -- you can add constrains more easily than you can remove them.

Comment: @dyp: Why would you write that instead of `HasIterator{T} void f(T, T)` which clearly shows the two arguments have the same type? [Why introduce two type template arguments `A` and `B` when we are going to require that they can only be one single type?]

Comment: Because I'm not very familiar with *template-introductions* :) Yes, `HasIterator{T} void f(T, T)` makes more sense. Originally, I thought of something like `void f(HasIterator a, HasIterator b) requires is_same<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::value` (in a hypothetical Concepts specification where `a` and `b` can have different types), but couldn't find a way to express it concisely.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking, the only reason I see for using template function is to enforce several parameters to have the same type. While with auto, each type deduction is independent from each other.

You can even mix template and auto if you want the first and third parameter to have the same type and generic type for the second.

```
template <class T> void barb(T a,auto b,T c){}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    barb(5," ",5); //ok 
    barb(5," ",5.6); //fails
    return 0;
}
```

As Oktalist wrote in the comment, you can use a using statement to get the parameter's type auto.